# Magento 2 Frontend and Backend coming broken

Tags: magento2, js-css

I have successfully installed Magento 2 on my xampp. But when I'm trying to get into the Admin section or see the front-end, then it is coming broken.

I have tried to fix the path issue but its of no use. Dashboard section pretends to load and keeps so, but never loads. The css and js seem's to be broken for the backend and frontend section.

Answer (score 0):

- Delete everything under /pub/static folder except .htaccess file.
- Open terminal and run following commands:

> cd [magento_root_folder]
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

- Remove /var/cache and /var/page_cache folders.
- Reload page and check.

Comment: I am using Magento 2.3, if try to run : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy   the message like Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.ma
gento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements.html. My PHP ver 7.2.10

Comment: @zus, the answer posted is more than 1.5 years old. Please specify in detail, what do you want to say?

Comment: Really thanks for your response, my issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/252069/57334   i am working with that.

Comment: Magento 2.3 installation error : https://snag.gy/oShfYR.jpg How can i solve this error? @Mohit Kumar Arora

Comment: You need to grant 777 permission to **`app/etc/env.php`** file.

Comment: In Magento 2.3 There is no env.php file under app/etc/ screenshot : https://snag.gy/9kYbJs.jpg

Comment: For now, you can grant 777 permission to **app/etc** folder recursively, so that Magento setup will be able to generate **env.php** file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86753/discussion-between-zus-and-mohit-kumar-arora).

Answer (score 0):

1. Add path = 'dev/static/sign' and value = 0 on the core_config_data table
2. Run in command prompt - sudo chmod -R 777 pub/static var/generation var/cache var
3. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
4. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
5. php bin/magento cache:clean