# After installing magento 2.3 admin login page cant open properly

Tags: admin-panel, magento2.3

After installing Magento 2.3, When I am trying to open the admin panel login screen is blank and my console contains an error as shown in the image. if anyone has a solution then please let me know.
[image: below is image that show error]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Find: /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:139

**find:**

```
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Replace with:**

```
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    $realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
    // and replace `$directory` with `$realDirectory`
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is really works for me

Comment: You are welcome. v2.2.6 is probably a better choice for now.

Comment: hi @manojpal its working fine, but frontend not getting home page http://prntscr.com/lpssgn   and at admin page http://prntscr.com/lpst7h   windows please advise

Comment: Hi,  @NagarajuKasa please apply all command.

Comment: @manojpal it was just freshly installed in windows thats it whether it is required?

Comment: I am also install in windows 10 , it's working fine https://prnt.sc/lpxsvi and admin page https://prnt.sc/lpxt3r

Comment: thank you so much for this one. I've spent 2days debugging because of this issue.

Comment: @manojpal I am also facing the same issues as Nagarjuna.
After applying your fix, able to login to admin page but now status is same as Nagarjuna
What do you mean by applying all commands?

Comment: Apply upgrade and static deploy command