# Magento 2 admin auth panel not displaying

Tags: magento2, admin, localhost

I have been trying to find a solution to this error for nearly 2 hours now in vain.

I recently downloaded **Magento 2** and set it up in my **localhost** windows.

When I go to my admin page, the sign in panel which is supposed to display (from tutorials I've watched) isn't displaying, instead I'm only getting this plain color background.

the default store front (localhost/magento/) shows up with the basic header and footer with the message "CMS homepage content goes here."

Has anyone had the same issue/is familiar with this issue? If so, help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Tim

[image]

Comment: Which magento version ?

Comment: @WebDeveloper Magento 2.3 (community)

Comment: Please try below solution and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After installing magento 2.3 admin login page cant open properly](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252069/after-installing-magento-2-3-admin-login-page-cant-open-properly)

Comment: @MGento could be a duplicate, though my solution was different to that given on that question.

Comment: @TomothyKA, I don't see any difference between the accepted answer of that question and the solution for this question. By context, both the questions are same and the solution is the same. Please have a look.

Comment: @MGento Look at my comments to the solution below. What fixed my issue was provided in the Github link (not the actual code provided).

Comment: @TimothyKA, then I wonder why the solution here, is marked as accepted ! It confuses the readers.

Comment: @MGento, Is it cool now !!!

Comment: @Web Developer, Cool. :) Have a great day.

Comment: @TimothyKA and MGento you too Buddies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's causing you problem due to you are on windows.

Give a try to below workaround.

**Check this issue also reported on Git. Its core bug for windows system.**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19480#issue-386162790

Comment: I tried the code provided above and got: 

"There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons."

I then tried the code provided in the github link:

replacing:  (:138) 

-->   $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);

with

-->  $realPath = str_replace('\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));

which turned out to work!

Thank you both for your help, I really appriciate it!

NOTE: I tried combining both to see what would happen and it gave me the first error message.

Comment: Happy to help you. Please give up vote to consider it as right answer So. Other member can take advantage from it.

Comment: EDIT: I made a typo in the code that solved the issue: instead of    --> "$realPath = str_replace('\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));    

it's   --> "$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));"

Comment: I need 15 reputation to upvote. Once I achieve that feat, I will upvote the solution lol