# Images are not loading in frontend and admin panel is not loading in backend in freshly installed magento 2.4.7

Tags: magento2.4, frontend, backend, admin-panel, xampp

As my question states, I have installed magento 2.4.7-beta1 on xampp 8.2.12 in windows 11 with composer 2.6.5 and elasticesearch 7.16.3 freshly. However any images on frontend and magento admin panel on the backend are not being displayed and I'm receiving static blank pages instead.

[image: Images not being loaded on frontend]

[image: Absolute grey blank page in admin panel url]

I've had tried the following solutions like [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92399/magento-2-images-not-showing-in-frontend) & [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252312/magento-2-admin-auth-panel-not-displaying) and yet it is to no avail. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

from magento root, run the following command from CLI.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```

Comment: Please do tell me if I'm wrong but how do I run "sudo" & "chmod" commands on a windows CLI? As for the rest of the commands I've already ran them several times now and also I'm running magento locally and the pub folder has full access control granted to all users on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

if you install magento windows system then change below file.

Step 1 : go to
vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php

find code function => validateURLScheme

```
if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes)) {
        return false;
    }
```

to

```
 if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && strlen($url['scheme']) > 1 && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes)) {
    return false;
    }
```

Step 2 : go to magento directory vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php

find function => isPathInDirectories

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

to

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

After apply below commands.

```
 php bin/magento s:up
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile
 php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f 
 php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: Thank you for your help however I had already made those changes in the validator & gd2 files during magento setup and also had ran those commands afterwards from my magento root folder with my CLI and I double checked the functions as stated and ran the commands again but it still didn't change a thing i.e., this the same static page on frontend & grey blank page on backend in place admin panel. Any thoughts?

Comment: please delete folders pub/static/frontend and pub/static/adminhtml and pub/static/deployed-version.text and reminder don't delete .htaccess file.

after apply commands.

php bin/magento s:up
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile
 php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f 
 php bin/magento c:f
 php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: I deleted the frontend & adminhtml folders with the deployed-version.txt as mentioned without deleting the htaccess file and ran the commands on root CLI and still no improvement. Still the same static pages on browser.

Comment: hello dear, magento var/log directory shows .log file. so please check it. tell me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help again but since I wasn't getting much solution on my problem so I reverted back to 2.4.6-p1 and that solved the issue. I think there's some internal error in one of the config files of 2.4.7 update which may have caused the problem. But still thank you for your time.

Comment: hello dear, my side suggested you work on Ubuntu.