# After installing magento 2.3.1, page can not open properly

Tags: magento2.3.1, home-page

After installing Magento 2.3.1 with sample data on my localhost, When I am trying to open the home page it shows blank. My console contains an error as shown in the image. Please help.. Thanks!

[image: error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2.3.1 is not working in Xampp](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269104/magento-2-3-1-is-not-working-in-xampp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please run below commands:

> rm -rf generated/* var/cache/* pub/static/*
>
> php bin/magento s:d:c
>
> php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:s:d -f
>
> php bin/magrnto c:f

and check

Comment: Thnx It worked! I run these commands and also changed this thing for admin panel: URL: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252069/after-installing-magento-2-3-admin-login-page-cant-open-properly