# Dashboard is loading after login in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

My login page didn't show after successfully install Magento2.
Then solve the issue from below link

> [After installing magento 2.3 admin login page cant open properly](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252069/after-installing-magento-2-3-admin-login-page-cant-open-properly)

After successfully login My Admin dashboard isn't load fully. Only loading icon is shown.
I upload an image for better understand.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run this - `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` then
`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: please explain me where to run ? I am using windows 10.

Comment: In open command window, from magento root folder

Answer (score 0):

Using the xampp so open the command line and goes to your magento root.

Run the this command :-

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

`php bin/magento c:c`

`php bin/magento c:f`

After check...

Comment: Hello @Arafat helpful this answer so accept because useful other communitys