# Invalid template File after installing on Windows

Tags: magento2, error, template, windows

[image]I am just freshly installed Magento 2.3 on Windows 10 . When i load the url for front end , the templates are not loading correctly and there is Dark blank page when loading admin url. I found this error on the log. Above screenshot is how the front-end looks like now

```
[2020-05-04 07:19:44] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/wysiwyg/active_editor.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'theme.active.editor' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:44] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-translation/view/base/templates/translate.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Translation' block's name: 'translate' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:44] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/components.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.components' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:44] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/calendar.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.calendar' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:44] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'logger' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:44] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/header.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'logo' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:44] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'admin.login' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:44] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'copyright' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:46] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:46] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/wysiwyg/active_editor.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'theme.active.editor' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:46] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-translation/view/base/templates/translate.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Translation' block's name: 'translate' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:46] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/components.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.components' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:46] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/calendar.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.calendar' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:46] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'logger' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:46] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/header.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'logo' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:46] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'admin.login' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:46] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'copyright' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:48] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:48] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/wysiwyg/active_editor.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'theme.active.editor' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:48] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-translation/view/base/templates/translate.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Translation' block's name: 'translate' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:48] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/components.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.components' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:48] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/calendar.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.calendar' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:48] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'logger' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:48] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/header.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'logo' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:48] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'admin.login' [] []
[2020-05-04 07:19:48] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'copyright' [] []
```

Can someone tell why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this links and replace this links code your file.

[After installing magento 2.3 admin login page cant open properly](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252069/after-installing-magento-2-3-admin-login-page-cant-open-properly)

And after run `php bin/magento c:f` and check output.

Hope this help you

Thanks...

Comment: Hello @Mr Zid it's help or not ???

Answer (score 0):

How to solve the Magento 2.3 admin page blank issue:

**Go to a path :-** m2directory/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:114

Find the below string:

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

**and replace it with:**

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

More reference check this [link](https://magecomp.com/blog/resolve-blank-page-issue-while-installing-magento-2/).